# Bootstrap 3 - 2 columns of different heights

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a specific layout using Bootstrap 3. I could easily accomplish this in straight CSS/HTML, but I would like to stick with Bootstrap classes if possible. I have other labels and fields on this same page.

```
+---------+-------------+
| Label   |  Textbox    |    <--- Exist and are fine
+---------+-------------+

+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| Label   |  Textbox    | This is multiline |
+---------+-------------+ column that will  |    <--- STUMPED!
                        | contain text and  |
+---------+-------------+ need to be        |
| Label   |  Textbox    | responsive-fluid  |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+
```

The existing form fields are displayed with this code which I would like to integrate in the multi-column/multi-row layout above:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" value="Value" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so many different layouts and Bootstrap classes (push, pull...) but I get really messy positioning no matter what I try. How would I accomplish this layout using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can make 2 containers in a row, something like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxG74/8/)

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" value="Value" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container col-xs-6">
        <label for="Name" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" value="Value" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
            <label for="Name" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" value="Value" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
            <label for="Name" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" value="Value" name="Name" id="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p>This is multiline column that will contain text and need to be responsive-fluid.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that and I think I can work with the example. Thank you. Do you know what needs to be done to it so that when the screen is narrower the labels and input fields go full width and known the bottom container below everything? Thanks!

Comment: Check here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete That mean you can use col-lg, col-md, col-sm or col-xs, whatever you need for each element